# c# check if list contains an existing element (not null)

Tags: c#, list, class, unity-game-engine, count

Is there some equivalent to `myTestList.Count` that will only count not-nullable fields?

For example I want to do certain things when I know that between some null elements is one existing element.

This is the behaviour I want, but can this be achieved also with pre-existing functions?

```
if(myList.Count > 0){
    for(int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++){
        if(myList[i] != null){
            DoSomething();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you have myList[0] = null, myList[1] = something, myList[2] = null? How do you have a not null in between nulls or did I completely misread this?

Comment: err yes the thing is in unity you can assign elements to fields in the inspector that come after a null element.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the linq `Any` method:

```
if (myList.Any(i => i != null))
{
    DoSomeThing();
}
```

Comment: what if a list is null.. will i get object not set to a reference... ?

Comment: @Thameem, you will. In that case, use something like `if (myList != null && myList.Any(i => i != null)))`

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't fussed about checking a specific index of the list not being null and just want to check there is something in the list you could use this.

```
if(myList != null && myList.Any())
{ 
   DoSomething();
}
```